# How To Set Made For Children In Youtube API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

Youtube is now enforcing the FTC's COPPA act. That means all creators need to specify whether or not their video is made for children.

I have an app which will livestream and upload video via the Java youtube API. But even with the newest API there does not seem to be a way to specify whether or not the video is made for children. Does anyone know what to use to specify this and how? Is it a hidden property in the `snippets` object? Thanks.

Comment: I honestly have no idea how you can accomplish this, but, I would check first its documentation - either their YouTube Creators's documentation or any related with it. I doubt YouTube Data API is updated compared to actual features found in their website and/or mobile version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YouTube seem to have updated the API documentation now.

As one example of where it's mentioned: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/revision_history

I've just started trying it out and it seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

So, guys when you are uploading a video, in the status field add a property called "selfDeclaredMadeForKids". You can set its value as True or False.

The code below is in #python.

```
status=dict(
        privacyStatus='public',
        selfDeclaredMadeForKids=False 
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9527654?ref_topic=9257782&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1) official support document says:

> We'll make the audience selection tool available to third-party applications and the YouTube API Services in the near future. For now, please use YouTube Studio to upload made for kid's content.

**08.01.2020.**

There seem to be no API references that allow streams or videos to be marked as "Made for Kids" or "Not Made for Kids".

Currently, the only way is via channel settings for all videos/streams or for each stream/video independently.

Further information will be provided via updates to this answer.